# Visual Studio XML comments from .cs to file in database project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xml-comments

Is it possible to create a cref from c# codes to a file in a database project so you can ctrl + click to navigate to it like you can with .cs files?

e.g. Say I have some data access code that uses a pacakge/procedure in some other database project:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="Link.To.The.Package"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vehicle"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override CommandWrapper InitializeCommand(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
       .....some code that executes some proc:  "packageName.proc"
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if ReSharper provides this if VS doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `href` instead of `cref`, and then the `file://` protocol (exactly like you would in plain html):

```
/// <see href="file://somefile"/>
```